# UIEvent timestamp

Tags: iphone, events, touch

When handling a UIButton touch, you are given a UIEvent object.  The UIEvent object has a timestamp which the Apple documentation states as being "the time that the event was created" (UIEvent Class Reference). In the documentation on the Main Event Loop, it states that: "The application object obtains the topmost object in the event queue, converts it to an event object (UIEvent) ..."

Does [UIEvent timestamp] refer to the time at which the UIEvent object is created (i.e. after processing the touch event off of the main run loop and hance not remotely real-time) or does it refer to the time that the underlying touch object was created (and hence as close as possible to representing the actual time of the user touch9?

Comment: In what situation would the distinction be important? Note that the time differential between the two is probably no more than a few milliseconds.

Comment: It is the few milliseconds that I am concerned about. I need to time the actual touch relative to a musical sequence that is playing. The shortest period between notes is 20ms so a 2ms lag will give me a 10% error which is no good.  Further, as you imply with the word 'probably', the time difference is indeterminate - it could be a lot bigger than 2ms.  It is OK if I process the event after a delay but I do need to know as accurately as possible when the event actually occured (relative to the system clock)

Comment: Arguably humans aren't able to distinguish the difference between 0ms of delay and 20ms of delay.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check, setup a view to log the timestamps of the touches, and then configure a button to lock the main thread for a few seconds (get a for loop to count to a 100 million).

While the main thread is spinning, tap your logging view, then examine the timestamps- if they're evenly spaced the OS does the timestamp, and it's accurate.